# Baby parsnips vs. parsley root

Tags: flavor, parsnip

I cooked parsnips for the first time this week (glad I did - delicious).  When the produce clerk pointed them out, I asked if he had baby parsnips instead (as the recipe called for them).

He pointed out parsley root, which looked very similar.  I did a search while in the store (and got in many shoppers' way), but could not find whether they were the same thing definitively.

A follow up question would be, if they aren't in fact the same thing, had I chosen to make this dish (roast veggies and chicken), how would the taste have differed for the parsley roots?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Parsley root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsley#Root_parsley) is not the same as [parsnip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsnip). It tastes more like parsley, which is not really a surprise. Parsley roots don't get as sweet and delicious when you roast them as parsnips do, in my opinion - I get plenty of both from my Community Supported Agriculture box and buy a lot of parsnips as well.

If you can't find parsnips you could use parsley root as a substitute rather than going without. On the matter of "baby" parsnips --  I just cut the large ones into more pieces. The centre of the largest ones are woody sometimes, but unless it's 4" or more across (which I have seen) you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: beat me to it @Kate Gregory!

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not the same.

Parsnips are [*Pastinaca sativa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsnip), parsley roots are roots of [Petroselinum crispum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsley).

They are interchangeable only to a degree:
Parsnips are a lot milder, with a sweet note and a lot more tender. Parsley is sometimes slightly sharp, can be more fibrous, especially the core, and takes longer to cook.